# Use of undefined constant with angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I am attempting to have a random first and last name generated based on gender and filled into a form. I'm using angular `$http` and am pretty new to angular in general. I get this error every time I load the

```
 Use of undefined constant firstName - assumed 'firstName'
```

My View:

```
 @section('content')
 <form ng-app="getNameApp" ng-controller="getNameController">

   Male<input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="male" name="gender" /><br />
   Female<input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="female" name="gender" /><br />

   <input type="text" ng-model="{{ firstName }}" name="firstName" />
   <input type="text" ng-if="{{ lastName }}" value="{{ lastName.body }}" name="lastName" />

   <button ng-click="randomNameController()">Randomize</button>
</form>
@stop
```

My JS

```
angular.module('getNameApp', [])
.controller('getNameController', getNameController);

function getNameController ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.gender = 'male';

   var randomName = $http({
       url: '/randomName',
       method: "GET",
       params: {gender: $scope.gender}
   });

   randomName.success(function(data) {
       $scope.firstName = data.firstName;
       $scope.lastName = data.lastName;
   });
   randomName.error(function() {
       document.write(randomName);
   });
```

}

My Controller

```
 public function randomName () {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $gender = Input::get('gender');

    if ($gender == 'male') {
        $names = [
            'firstName' => $faker->firstNameMale
        ];
    } else {
        $names = [
            'firstName' => $faker->firstNameFemale
        ];
    }
    $names['lastName'] = $faker->lastName;
    return $names;
}
```

edit: I checked the network tab of inspect element and it says 500 internal server error with createCharacter. (route to page)

Comment: Remove brackets from ngmodel. You shouldnt put that for ngmodel.

Comment: I'm sad I can only up-vote that once with how awesome that is. :) the randomize button doesn't work but that is a huge improvement

Comment: What are you actually doing here `ng-click="randomNameController()` ? What is `ng-click="randomNameController()`  ? How does your data looks like. Here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDTO0l?p=preview

Comment: It is supposed to reload a different first and last name. I thought recalling the function would work. Evidently not.

Comment: It will work. But you would need to implement it. DO you have that code?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not understanding it. If I call the randomNameController again will it not return a new first and last name?

Comment: You cannot call controller like that. Controllers are instantiated and you cannot call a controller like a method. You should instead write the logic of shuffling probably in a service that holds the data (depends on how complex it is), or just as a method in the controller itself. Remember with angular you just deal with bindings   and not DOM. So if you bind a different data it will reflect there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59779/discussion-between-helliax-and-psl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the direct answer to this question is, no brackets on `ng-model=""`. That being said, I had lots of problems in my code and the working version of it is below. Hopefully it helps someone having similar problems. I know it's not the cleanest.

This code creates a form with a randomly generated name based on gender. you can select a gender and hit randomize to fill a different name. I am using the https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker library to generate a name.

View:

```
 <form ng-app="getNameApp" ng-controller="getNameController">

  Male<input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="male" name="gender" /><br />
  Female<input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="female" name="gender" /><br />

  <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" name="firstName" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" name="lastName" />

  <button ng-click="generate(gender)">Randomize</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
 angular.module('getNameApp', []).controller('getNameController', getNameController);
```

function getNameController ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.gender = 'male';

```
$scope.generate = function (gender) {
    var randomName = $http({
        url: '/randomName',
        method: "GET",
        params: {gender: gender}
    });

    randomName.success(function (data) {
        var names = {
            firstName: data.firstName,
            lastName: data.lastName
        };
        $scope.firstName = names.firstName;
        $scope.lastName = names.lastName;

    });
    randomName.error(function () {
        document.write(randomName);
    });
    return $scope;

};

   $scope.generate($scope.gender);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function randomName () {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $gender = Input::get('gender');

    if ($gender == 'male') {
        $names = [
            'firstName' => $faker->firstNameMale
        ];
    } else if ($gender == 'female') {
        $names = [
            'firstName' => $faker->firstNameFemale
        ];
    }
    $names['lastName'] = $faker->lastName;
    return $names;
}
```

Comment: I was using document.write just as a quick way to test my code. I figured I needed `return $scope` since it is within a function.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seen that kind of error, however you have an issue, you are trying to get the firstName from promise

```
randomName.success(function() {
     $scope.firstName = randomName.firstName; //<-- Here randomName is a promise not data
     $scope.lastName = randomName.lastName;
  });
```

Instead get the data which comes as the first argument of the `success` callback,

```
 randomName.success(function(data) {
     $scope.firstName = data.firstName; 
     $scope.lastName = data.lastName;
  });
```

Comment: You are displaying firstname which is an object as value?

Comment: It wasn't even loading the js function at all. New problems though. I've been wrong with this before, make a new questions or just edit this one?